# Dell XPS 15 9500 Ubuntu poor battery

Tags: drivers, nvidia, dell, power-management, battery

As the title says. The 86WHR battery is huge! I have the 15'' variant with

`15.6" FHD+ (1920 x 1200) InfinityEdge Non-Touch Anti-Glare 500-Nit Display`

`NVIDIA® GeForce® GTX 1650 Ti 4GB GDDR6`

I have nvidia drivers installed and even after disabling the GPU, the battery performance of the laptop tops out 4 or so hours of web-use in medium screen brightness. Not sure what I am doing wrong but anyone can comment?

With GPU on the battery estimation is 2 hours

Comment: For context the Windows 10 battery is ~10 hours or more